# call python from php

Tags: php, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call Python From PHP And Get Return Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726551/call-python-from-php-and-get-return-code)

probably a very stupid question
I have a python module lets say hi.py which have the following

```
print "hi"
```

now I want to execute this file from php

```
<?php

#code here
?>
```

So how do I call that python file from php.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call+python+from+php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to invoke Python.

Example:

```
$output = array();
exec("python hi.py", $output);
var_dump( $output);
```

There are other commands for executing commands on the machine PHP is running on, see [the docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

Comment: when id do the above.. There is no output in the browser.. How do I get that "hi" output on the browser

Comment: use `exec("command", $output_array);` it's in a [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: @Fraz - I've updated my answer to show you how to capture the output. As Jan Vorcak pointed out, it is in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

you can call php exec function and call

```
python -c "print 'hi'"
```

or if you have larger module you can use

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

so in the end I'd use

```
exec("python -m hi");
```

1. and don't forget to configure PYTHON_PATH on your server if needed
2. be careful doing this kind of stuff