# call python selenium from php

Tags: php, python, selenium

I have a python script for scraping with selenium. When i call my script with terminal like this

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/scraping.py
```

i have no problem my scraping work

Went a try to call the same script with php is not working .

on my python script a have this

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

driver =webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")

print(page)
```

when i delete this line

```
driver =webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")
```

in i put juste `print('test')`

i this work

for my php file y tried

[Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

[Execute Python script from Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811253/execute-python-script-from-php)

[How to call a Python Script from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497540/how-to-call-a-python-script-from-php)

[call python from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303923/call-python-from-php)

but nothing works

i change my permission file to `chmod 777 scraping.py` in tried to change group file for `www-data` i tried to put www-data to soduers file

in my php code i have tri this

```
 output = array(); 
exec("/usr/bin/python3 /home/scraping.py",$output);
 var_dump( $output); 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python3 /home/scraping.py');
 $output = shell_exec($command);
 echo $output;

 ob_start(); 
passthru('/usr/bin/python3 /home/scraping.py');
```

$output =ob_get_clean()

**EDIT**

I have found my problem

The problem is the log file generate by phantomjs and and shebang to top in my code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from selenium import webdriver

driver =webdriver.PhantomJS( service_log_path='/home/ghostdriver.log'executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")

print(page)
```

and after change the permission of the ghostdriver.log for the www-data can read id you have a error again put the group www-data in the sudoers file with no passwd

Comment: Post your PHP code